# How to reference value of dynamic field in asp modalpopup

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, dynamic, modalpopupextender

I have a modalpopup extender that is shown when the user clicks an 'Add' button. I can create a dynamic textbox on that popup.

My problem is I can't get a reference to that textbox in the codebehind.

I have added a 'textchanged' event handler to the textbox but since it needs the AutoPostBack = true (I think), the modalpopup is destroyed before my event fires! And even if I reshow the modalpopup the dynamic field is now gone.

Here is the ASP for the modalpopup:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="PayDetail_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" PopupControlID="PayDetailPopupPanel" TargetControlID="btnShowDetailPopup"
                    CancelControlID="btnClosePayDetail" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
 </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

 <asp:Button ID="btnShowDetailPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" />
 <asp:Panel ID="PayDetailPopupPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPayPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">
                        <asp:table id="addClaimDetailTable" runat="server" class="table" >
                            <asp:TableRow style="display:none">
                                <asp:TableCell >
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPayHeaderID" runat="server" Text="Pay Header ID:"></asp:Label>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell >

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayHeaderID" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </asp:table>
 </asp:Panel>
```

I am creating a dynamic textbox in codebehind like this:

```
        //add dynamic fields
        TableRow tRow = new TableRow(); //row
        TableCell hCell = new TableCell(); //header
        TableCell dCell = new TableCell(); //data

        Label lblHeader = new Label();
        lblHeader.ID = "lblMedicare";
        lblHeader.Text = "Medicare:";
        TextBox txtData = new TextBox();
        txtData.ID = "txtMedicare";
        txtData.Text = "";
        txtData.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtData_TextChanged);
        txtData.AutoPostBack = true;
        //and add to LIST
        PayDetailDynamicList.Add(txtData);
        //myValue = txtData.ID;


        hCell.Controls.Add(lblHeader);
        dCell.Controls.Add(txtData);
        tRow.Controls.Add(hCell);
        tRow.Controls.Add(dCell);

        addClaimDetailTable.Controls.Add(tRow);
```

I am storing the textbox in a static list:

```
     static List<TextBox> PayDetailDynamicList = new List<TextBox>();
```

Here is the codebehind for the eventhandler:

```
    void txtData_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;

        if (t == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("sender not a textbox", "sender");

        //add value to list?
        string value = t.Text;
        string id = t.ID;
    }
```

My question is: how can I get into the eventhandler to store the user entered data?  Or how can I get a reference to this dynamic textbox so I can retrieve the value?

Is there a better way to do this?  Use a form for my modalpopup?  If I knew jquery and ajax I could probably do the dynamic fields that way but I don't...

Any help is appreciated!  Let me know if you need more details... thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: well this isn't exactly the answer I was hoping for but it did the trick. I ended up resolving my problem by using 10 fixed fields on the modalpopup form and just using a loop to make them visible/not-visible depending on the data requirements... not truly dynamic but with deadlines fast approaching I couldn't waste time trying to figure it out any more.

Comment: I got exactly same problem. Should I move with the fixed Textboxes ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
TextBox MyTextBox = PayDetail_ModalPopupExtender.FindControl("txtMedicare") as TextBox;
```

Here is the information about Control.FindControl
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm not sure it's that simple. In this case, when I try that code MyTexBox is null. I've read some articles about viewstate and I'm thinking the dynamic textbox is out of scope at the time I'm trying to read the value?

Comment: I update my answer after reading your case more precisely. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Eldar - but still no joy.  The controls collection for the modalpopup is null once I get to the Click event of the Save button on the popup...

Comment: I look into details while elephant pass through )